# Issues with saving xml document to xml file in the output directory. c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm making an application that loads and saves profile nodes to an external xml document in my output directory. It worked fine when I was opening it from my Assets folder but since that is read only (I think) I need to have it read and write from the output directory or another folder. 
Like this:

```
XmlDocument users = new XmlDocument();
users.Load("users.xml");
```

However I get this error when this code runs:

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/users.xml"."

I've ticked the secondary storage permissions but i'm still a bit confused about just referencing a file in the output directory.

Would also appreciate the help for saving too as I assume the same error will occur:

```
users.DocumentElement.AppendChild(user);
users.Save("users.xml");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to write to user directory

Comment: Use a definite folder for example yourActivity.FilesDir.AbsolutePath this is an internal folder given to the applications to store their data

Comment: @user2912553 is there an example of this i could have a look at? like where i would put that internal folder path?

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin form you can try this code to load xml file from PCL project.

```
var assembly = typeof(TestClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(“PrjectName.FileName”);
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BuildOptions>)); var listData = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```